# Why doesn't Benchmarking (Phoronix) Test Suits make complete use of CPU

Tags: linux, benchmarking, performance-testing

I am trying to benchmark my ubuntu server and got to know that the `Phoronix Test Suite` is the most comprehensive test suite for performance testing.

A ran a combined `server` and `computational` suits couple of times. But when I check my dashboard and logs, I see that the max CPU usage was only upto 25%

The benchmark tests are suppose to evaluate the max performance capabilities of your system, then how come they only use 25% of CPU and if they aren't making the full use of CPU then how does it justify the integrity of these tests results.

Are there any better test suits to evaluate linux system performance.

Comment: 25% seems like a single core running at 100% on a quad core CPU.

Comment: Yeah I wondered the same, but I guess there's no concrete way of knowing it. I am going to try to apply same tests on a 8 core server to see if its true. Open for more suggestions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Michal's comment, I figured it out that the benchmarking tests were single threaded and hence utilized only one core.

I tried running the same tests on a 2 and 8 core machines and I got `MAX CPU` usage to roughly ~50% and ~12.5%

To check the multi-core performance we need to find other alternatives like `Multi-Core` suite.

Answer (score 0):

As you said `The benchmark tests are suppose to evaluate the max performance capabilities of your system`, and in a system CPU is a single component and the percent utilization shows only the ratio of CPU working and CPU idle waiting.
You should check the load average value, it should be around or over 4 in a fully bogged down system that has a 4 cores.

Comment: The parameter that read 25% was `MAX CPU Usage` and not total or average usage. There's no such thing as `RATIO` in the parameters.

Answer (score 0):

lmbench, sysbench, apache benchmark, fio are good options other than phoronix. The problem with phoronix is that it has too many options and requires a ton of dependencies. Only if you are super serious benchmark engineer who knows how each of the phoronix dependency benchmark tool works I do not recommend it.